# Cascaded Shadow Map - Orthographic Projection Issues

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d

I am attempting to upgrade the shadow map rendering in my OpenGL game to the Cascaded Shadow Map method described in [this OGLdev tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial49/tutorial49.html). Everything works fine except at certain camera angles the shadow map doesn't cover the entire view frustum.

[There's a quick video of the problem here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGJEbx1Zp4w), where I toggle between the final rendered scene and the middle shadow slice texture. You can see that the shadows of the player are cut off too early in the shadow texture (white view).

Each shadow map is rendered into its own FBO and sampled later when performing post-processing (simple fragDepth > textureDepth). The code is as follows:

```
const int SLICE_AMOUNT = 3;
Matrix4[] lightViewSpaces = new Matrix4[SLICE_AMOUNT];
Matrix4[] shadowProjections = new Matrix4[SLICE_AMOUNT];
OrthoInfo[] orthoInfo = new OrthoInfo[SLICE_AMOUNT];

const float zNear = 1;
const float zFar = 256;

Vector3 up = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
Vector3 LightDirection = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1).Normalized();

float[] cascadeEnds = new float[SLICE_AMOUNT + 1]
{
    zNear,
    32f,
    64f,
    zFar,
};        

Vector3[] frustumCenters = new Vector3[SLICE_AMOUNT];


public void RenderShadowShader()
{
    CalculateOrthographicFrustums();

    // Create shadows maps at each view frustum slice
    for (int i = 0; i < SLICE_AMOUNT; i++)
    {
        // Bind the shadow map FBO for this slice
        Gl.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.DrawFramebuffer, CurrentCollection.shadowFBO[i]);

        var o = orthoInfo[i];

        // Combine the light view projection and orthographic projection                                   -200 for leniency
        shadowProjections[i] = lightViewSpaces[i] * Matrix4.CreateOrthoProjection(o.l, o.t, o.r, o.b, o.n - 200, o.f - o.n);

        Gl.Viewport(0, 0, (int)screenWidth, (int)screenHeight);
        Gl.Clear(ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        Gl.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        Gl.Disable(EnableCap.CullFace);

        // Render scene objects to the shadowFBO depth buffer
        RenderShadowMeshes(shadowProjections[i]);
    }
}

// Convert each view frustum slice to light space
void CalculateOrthographicFrustums()
{
    // Get the world view projection from player camera
    Matrix4 Cam = Matrix4.CreateLookAt(player.headPosition, player.headPosition - player.LookAtVector(), up);
    Matrix4 worldViewProj = Cam.Inverse();

    var aspectRatio = screenHeight / screenWidth;
    var tanHalfHFOV = (float)Math.Tan(Math.PI * (parent.FieldOfView / 180.0) / 2.0);
    var tanHalfVFOV = (float)Math.Tan(Math.PI * (parent.FieldOfView / 180.0) * aspectRatio / 2.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < SLICE_AMOUNT; i++)
    {
        float xn = cascadeEnds[i] * tanHalfHFOV;
        float xf = cascadeEnds[i + 1] * tanHalfHFOV;
        float yn = cascadeEnds[i] * tanHalfVFOV;
        float yf = cascadeEnds[i + 1] * tanHalfVFOV;

        Vector4[] frustumCorners =
        { 
            // Near face
            new Vector4(xn,   yn, cascadeEnds[i], 1.0),
            new Vector4(-xn,  yn, cascadeEnds[i], 1.0),
            new Vector4(xn,  -yn, cascadeEnds[i], 1.0),
            new Vector4(-xn, -yn, cascadeEnds[i], 1.0),

            // Far face                 
            new Vector4(xf,   yf, cascadeEnds[i + 1], 1.0),
            new Vector4(-xf,  yf, cascadeEnds[i + 1], 1.0),
            new Vector4(xf,  -yf, cascadeEnds[i + 1], 1.0),
            new Vector4(-xf, -yf, cascadeEnds[i + 1], 1.0)
        };

        // Store the frustum corners in light space
        var frustumCornersLS = new Vector4[8];

        // Transform frustum corners to world space
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            frustumCorners[j] *= worldViewProj;

        frustumCenters[i] = GetFrustumCenter(frustumCorners);

        // Create light view projection from from world-space frustum center
        lightViewSpaces[i] = Matrix4.CreateLookAt(frustumCenters[i] + LightDirection, frustumCenters[i], up);

        // Convert frustum corners to light-space
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            frustumCornersLS[j] = frustumCorners[j] * lightViewSpaces[i];

        // Calculate AABB of light-space frustum
        GetMinMax(frustumCornersLS, out Vector3 min, out Vector3 max);

        // Store AABB in orthoInfo
        orthoInfo[i].r = max.X;
        orthoInfo[i].l = min.X;
        orthoInfo[i].b = min.Y;
        orthoInfo[i].t = max.Y;
        orthoInfo[i].f = max.Z;
        orthoInfo[i].n = min.Z;
    }
}
```

The part of this that that I think may be the problem is the conversion of the frustum corners to light space. Whilst it gets the location of the shadows right, it doesn't seem to cope when I change the camera angle:

```
// Create light view projection from from world-space frustum center
lightViewSpaces[i] = Matrix4.CreateLookAt(frustumCenters[i] + LightDirection, frustumCenters[i], up);
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide more images and code if need be.

Comment: Why `lightViewSpaces[i] * Matrix4.CreateOrthoProjection(o.l, o.t, o.r, o.b, o.n - 200, o.f - o.n);`? Does it really just rotate and offset your ortho to center?

Comment: I think it should, is it correct args order in `CreateOrtho`?

Comment: `lightViewSpaces[i] * Matrix4.CreateOrthoProjection(o.l, o.t, o.r, o.b, o.n - 200, o.f - o.n);` is used to point the orthographic projection towards the center of each view frustum part, so that the shadow maps closest to the player camera has a higher resolution. I double checked and the arguments are in the correct order